# Entity Framework Core: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

We have a production app that is growing every day more and it is managing a lot of asynchronous requests. We had backend composed by a PostgreSQL database and an ASP.NET Core 6 Web API.

The backend uses `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` with `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` to manage operations/queries on the database. From few days we are experiencing a lot of errors at frontend level when loading data and a lot of performance issues.

This is caused by:

```
2023-07-04 17:54:30.968 +00:00 [ERR] Connection id "0HMRQ47B5IT4M", Request id "0HMRQ47B5IT4M:00000001": An unhandled exception was thrown by the application.
System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
 ---> Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 53300: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<ReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|234_0(NpgsqlConnector connector, Boolean async, DataRowLoadingMode dataRowLoadingMode, Boolean readingNotifications, Boolean isReadingPrependedMessage)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|216_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.OpenNewConnector(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.PoolingDataSource.<Get>g__RentAsync|28_0(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternalAsync(Boolean errorsExpected, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(RelationalCommandParameterObject parameterObject, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.InitializeReaderAsync(AsyncEnumerator enumerator, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  Exception data:
    Severity: FATAL
    SqlState: 53300
    MessageText: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections
    File: postinit.c
    Line: 815
    Routine: InitPostgres
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`4 operation, Func`4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.SingleQueryingEnumerable`1.AsyncEnumerator.MoveNextAsync()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToListAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at MyAppCore.Api.Controllers.ArticlesController.GetArticlesWithQuery(Int32 first, Int32 fromId, Int32 take, Boolean includeSub) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyAppCore.Api/Controllers/ArticlesController.cs:line 67
   at lambda_method7(Closure, Object)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.AwaitableObjectResultExecutor.Execute(ActionContext actionContext, IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionMethodAsync>g__Awaited|12_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, ValueTask`1 actionResultValueTask)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeNextActionFilterAsync>g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeInnerFilterAsync>g__Awaited|13_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at MyAppCore.Api.Utilities.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context) in /home/vsts/work/1/s/MyAppCore.Api/Utilities/AuthenticationMiddleware.cs:line 65
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)
2023-07-04 17:54:31.041 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HMRQ47B5IT4M" received FIN.
2023-07-04 17:54:31.041 +00:00 [DBG] 'myAppContext' disposed.
2023-07-04 17:54:31.042 +00:00 [DBG] Disposing connection to database 'myApp_dev' on server ''.
2023-07-04 17:54:31.042 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HMRQ47B5IT4M" sending FIN because: "The client closed the connection."
2023-07-04 17:54:31.042 +00:00 [DBG] Connection id "0HMRQ47B5IT4M" disconnecting.
2023-07-04 17:54:31.042 +00:00 [DBG] Disposed connection to database 'myApp_dev' on server '' (0ms).
```

The context is generated using `dotnet-ef` tools with database first method and the context is add with normal DI pattern:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<myAppContext>(options =>
            options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("MYAPP_CONTEXT")));
```

This error is generated every time that the API receives more than 100 requests simultaneously, and sometimes they are >200. The async API pattern with Entity Framework Core open a new connection for every request even if the service by default is injected as scoped.

In fact simply executing `select * from pg_stat_activity;` query wee see exactly 100 opened connections, also in development environment if we try to simulate >100 simultaneously calls the result is the same: 100 opened connection that aren't disposed immediately once finished.

There are a lot of GitHub issue and StackOverflow don't answered question related to this problem. We think that increase the `max_connections` database parameter is not the right way.

How to solve this problem?

What is the correct implementation/usage of Entity Framework Core in enterprise environment? We think that >100 request in a 1/2 seconds time span is not too much for an enterprise app.

Comment: Have you done something like disabled pooling in your connection string? For high-traffic systems you want pooling enabled. EFCore's DbContext should wait on a pooled connection. You can also assign DbContexts from a Pool themselves /w EF Core using Services.AddDbContextPool which will help ensure requests wait on a set # of DbContexts. (Currently 128 by default) Though if you're expecting a large # of concurrent requests this would block requests as they try to get an available DbContext which likely wouldn't be desirable.

Comment: Some days ago I've added `Pooling=true` to my connection string, before it wasn't specified. Maybe the situation improve a little bit but the problem is still here. Only for reference this is the connection string: `Host=localhost;Database=mydb;Username=myuser;Password=mypsw;Pooling=true;`

Answer (score 1):

This involved a bit of reading around the details of how connection pooling is supported through NpgSql and PostgreSQL. By default NpgSql has an internal connection pool which is enabled by default with a pool size of 100. PostgreSQL itself does not implement any form of connection pooling, but has a limit to the # of active connections which is the error you are hitting. By default this is also set to 100.

While NpgSql on your web server should be pooling EF connections to your database so more than 100 web requests with scoped DbContexts will wait for a pooled connection to PostgreSQL, you will need to account for the fact that with the default 100 pool size and 100 active connections, the assumption is that this web server has exclusive access to the database. This means if you have an existing database connection open with PgAdmin or have any other apps/services periodically hitting the database while your API is getting hammered and hitting it's 100 pool size, you could hit this error as the pool cannot create it's 100th connection. For testing purposes you should be able to work around this by reserving a few connections for anyone hitting the database by setting the "Maximum Pool Size=95" or so in the connection string telling NpgSql to only pool up 95 connections, leaving a buffer of 5 on the database server. For situations where multiple developers are hitting a common test database, you should consider setting your development connection string to use a much lower maximum pool size to help prevent stepping over the limit.

If your web server is load balanced then your maximum pool size in the API connection string should reflect the # of load balance instances. For instance if the database server has a maximum of 100 connections and you want to load balance 4 API servers, then the connection string should have a maximum pool size of no more than 25 given you have 4 servers potentially opening connections to the same database. This doesn't work with dynamic load balancing where you might have 2, 4, or more web servers depending on load since you'll either need to configure them to use the worst-case (maximum load balance size) and risk starving them of Db Connections or risk running into this error if your load balancer fires up one too many web servers. In this case it would be better to implement the connection pooling on the database server itself (with load balancing and replication for truly large systems) and turn off NpgSql's internal pooling.

Depending on the resources available to the database server itself, you do have the option to increase the maximum connection limit on the database server itself. Keep in mind each active connection requires memory and still has to fight for things like I/O so it's not a case of going from 100 to 1000 connections. You can scale up a bit for servers with a lot of RAM and SSDs, but it will require some reading and may require some trial & error to see where the cut-off should be in terms of resource use & performance cost.

Ultimately for high volume systems you will want to ensure that database operations are kept as short as possible. So any optimizations to limit the number and complexity of reads is a good investment. For instance using projection to reduce Cartesian Products, performing batch operations using SQL statements rather than loading and updating entities one by one, etc. It's important to keep operations as efficient and fast as possible so that it minimizes the wait for a connection from a pool. If a database is serving 100 requests at a time, there is no reason that web servers are serving 1000's or 10's of thousands of requests, but they will be queuing when they need a database connection. Each connection use should be only if necessary and as short as absolutely possible. The API can do things like cache frequently used and infrequently changed reference data, etc. to reduce the query complexity and size.

Hopefully this should give you some insight into things to try to avoid running into this error. Some useful links for info on PostgreSQL/NpgSql and pooling I came across:

https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Number_Of_Database_Connections

[https://arctype.com/blog/connnection-pooling-postgres/#:~:text=comes%20into%20play.-,What%20is%20connection%20pooling%3F,active%20connection%20to%20the%20user](https://arctype.com/blog/connnection-pooling-postgres/#:%7E:text=comes%20into%20play.-,What%20is%20connection%20pooling%3F,active%20connection%20to%20the%20user).

https://www.npgsql.org/doc/compatibility.html?q=pgbouncer

https://www.pgpool.net/mediawiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Thanks for the good explanation, we know few of these concepts! We are afraid because it is the first time that we experience that, we found also a Microsoft article about DB Pooling but we think that another time that isn't the solution. It is crazy because on the web you can find a lot of theories but never a real solution. We are thinking about a migration to SQL Server that is able to manage a lot of simultaneous connections.

Comment: It's not easy to find examples because like all things, real-world examples are big, unique, complex, and often proprietary beasts. Someone can explain some of the problems they face and things they try, but you don't really get detail on the complete picture. Generally the first point to attack is ensuring your requests are as small and fast as possible, and aren't getting called more often than needed. For example microservices are great for somethings, but if running a large processing job, spinning up 200+ threads to all call a service that hits the database would be counter-productive.

Comment: In fact the strange thing is that in this case every request need max 100ms to be completed. So it isn't an intensive job per request.

Comment: There are many techniques and designs to help eliminate bottlenecks like connection pool limits, row locking, etc. Handing off heavy/frequent read requests to read-only replicas, employing a queue system with a worker thread pool to throttle high-volume requests that don't need immediate responses, and removing dependance on immediate execution,  then looking at vertical scaling for write operations (more resources to handle larger connection pools) or in extreme cases load balancing data horizontally.